# How to fix this error "gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/mohamedessam/Desktop/NodeJs/node_modules/bcrypt/build'"

Tags: node.js, linux, npm

I am trying to install bcrypt on Ububtu 18.04. I am using this command for installation:
 `sudo npm i --save bcrypt`
and I am getting an error.
This is the reported error:

```
> bcrypt@3.0.6 install /home/mohamedessam/Desktop/NodeJs/node_modules
/bcrypt
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download 
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for bcrypt@3.0.6 and 
node@8.10.0 (node-v57 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with 
node-gyp) 

node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home
/mohamedessam/Desktop/NodeJs/node_modules/bcrypt/lib' 

gyp ERR! configure error 

gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/mohamedessam
/Desktop/NodeJs/node_modules/bcrypt/build'

gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-54-generic

gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules
/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-
build" "--module=/home/mohamedessam/Desktop/NodeJs/node_modules/bcrypt
/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node" "--module_name=bcrypt_lib" "--
module_path=/home/mohamedessam/Desktop/NodeJs/node_modules/bcrypt
/lib/binding" "--napi_version=1" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--
napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v57"

gyp ERR! cwd /home/mohamedessam/Desktop/NodeJs/node_modules/bcrypt

gyp ERR! node -v v8.10.0

gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0

gyp ERR! not ok 

node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 

node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/bin/node /usr/local
/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure 
--fallback-to-build --module=/home/mohamedessam/Desktop/NodeJs
/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib 
--module_path=/home/mohamedessam/Desktop/NodeJs/node_modules/bcrypt
/lib/binding --napi_version=1 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 
--node_napi_label=node-v57' (1)

node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home
/mohamedessam/Desktop/NodeJs/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib
/util/compile.js:83:29)

node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)

node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)

node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose 
(internal/child_process.js:925:16)

node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit 
(internal/child_process.js:209:5)

node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-54-generic

node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/home/mohamedessam/Desktop
/NodeJs/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"

node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /home/mohamedessam/Desktop/NodeJs/node_modules
/bcrypt

node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v8.10.0

node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.12.0

node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 

Failed to execute '/usr/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules
/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build 
--module=/home/mohamedessam/Desktop/NodeJs/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding
/bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=/home/mohamedessam
/Desktop/NodeJs/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding --napi_version=1 
--node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v57' 
(1)

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 
(node_modules/fsevents):

npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for 
fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: 
{"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})


npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! bcrypt@3.0.6 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR! 

npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@3.0.6 install script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. It is likely 
additional logging output above.
```

It seems that npm doesn't have permission to install bcrypt.
After serching online I also tried this command:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /home/mohamedessam/Desktop/NodeJs/node_modules/,
sudo npm i --unsafe-perm
```

but it gives me the same error. What should I do in oredr to install it successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Resolving EACCES permissions errors when installing packages globally
If you see an EACCES error when you try to install a package globally, you can either:

Reinstall npm with a node version manager (recommended),
or
Manually change npm’s default directory
Reinstall npm with a node version manager§
This is the best way to avoid permissions issues. To reinstall npm with a node version manager, follow the steps in “Downloading and installing Node.js and npm”. You do not need to remove your current version of npm or Node.js before installing a node version manager.

Manually change npm’s default directory§
Note: This section does not apply to Microsoft Windows.
To minimize the chance of permissions errors, you can configure npm to use a different directory. In this example, you will create and use hidden directory in your home directory.

Back up your computer.
On the command line, in your home directory, create a directory for global installations:
 mkdir ~/.npm-global
Configure npm to use the new directory path:
 npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
In your preferred text editor, open or create a ~/.profile file and add this line:
 export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
On the command line, update your system variables:
 source ~/.profile
To test your new configuration, install a package globally without using sudo:
 npm install -g jshint
Instead of steps 2-4, you can use the corresponding ENV variable (e.g. if you don’t want to modify ~/.profile):

```
NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=~/.npm-global
```

Answer (score 0):

I gave 777 permission to the files with this command:-
`chmod -R 777 ./`
and worked for me then.